# Background colour expression brings up a surprising result

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I want a cell colour to change if a duplicate value appears. I have used this expression for Background Colour:

```
IIF(Previous(Fields!CustomerSurname.Value) = Fields!CustomerSurname.Value, "Red", Fields!CustomerSurname.Value)
```

This works fine but if the customer surname is 'Brown' or 'Grey' then the cell colour matches the colour of the surname, e.g. the surname 'Brown' creates a brown cell background, not red. This doesn't happen with other surnames, e.g. ones that are not the names of colours...

Any tips or guidance on how to avoid this would be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to change this to:

```
IIF(Previous(Fields!CustomerSurname.Value) = Fields!CustomerSurname.Value, "Red", "White")
```

(or whatever "standard" background colour you want).  If the current and previous fields didn't match your expression was returning the value of the field as the background colour, hence your result.